# collecting the sum of a field in java stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

consider the following class:

```
public class PersonalExpense {
    private String name;
    private int currentExpenses;

    ...
```

how to can i write a java stream "pipeline" that works in the same way as the first method (getRemainingCompanyBalance). this code results in an error.

> the list contains separate lists for each department. each entry in the sub-list is an instance of the class. name/cost:
>
> > de#1first"/9900,
> >     de#1second"/8700,
> >     de#2first"/8500,
> >     de#2second"/10000,
> >     de#3first"/7800,
> >     de#3second"/6900

```
    private static long getRemainingCompanyBalance ( long initialBalance, List<ArrayList<PersonalExpense>> total) {
        long remainingBalance = initialBalance;
        for (List<PersonalExpense> departmentExpense : total) {
            for (PersonalExpense personalExpense : departmentExpense) {
                System.out.println(personalExpense.getName());
                remainingBalance = remainingBalance - personalExpense.getCurrentExpenses();
            }
        }
        return remainingBalance;
    }

    public static long getRemainingCompanyBalanceLambda ( long initialBalance, List<ArrayList<PersonalExpense>> total) {
        long remainingBalance = initialBalance;


        Integer sum = total
        .stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(pe -> pe instanceof PersonalExpense)
        .map (pe -> (PersonalExpense) pe)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .mapToInt(PersonalExpense::getCurrentExpenses)
        .sum();


        return remainingBalance -= sum;
    }

}
```

i'm trying to collect costs, then subtract them from the balance

Comment: hmm I personally don't see this as a duplicate, it's not that plain simple as computing the `sum`, specially since the OP seems to not know what `flatMap` and the like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static long getRemainingCompanyBalanceLambda ( long initialBalance, List<ArrayList<PersonalExpense>> total) {

   int sum = total.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .mapToInt(PersonalExpense::getCurrentExpenses)
        .sum();

   return initialBalance - sum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got some unnecessary method calls. You don't need to filter the `Stream`, since it already contains just `PersonalExpense` instances, and you shouldn't collect it to a `List`, because that would prevent you from mapping it to an `IntStream` and computing the sum.

```
public static long getRemainingCompanyBalanceLambda ( long initialBalance, List<ArrayList<PersonalExpense>> total) {
    return initialBalance - total
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .mapToInt(PersonalExpense::getCurrentExpenses)
    .sum();
}
```

Comment: @Eugene that's true

Answer (score 0):

With `mapToInt` function

```
int sum = total.stream()
         .mapToInt(PersonalExpense::getCurrentExpenses)
         .sum();
```

With `summingInt` function

```
int sum = total.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.summingInt(PersonalExpense::getCurrentExpenses));
```